# Keeping margin and nav bar "responsive"

Tags: html, css, html-lists

As the title says, I'm trying to keep the margin and nav bar uniformed or responsive to the elements above. Both are in unordered lists. Obviously my heights of 130px is the problem but I can't seem to make it work with anything but px. I'd also like to add a % to the hiehgt of the nav but all margins seem to disappear when I do so.

I understand I'll most likely get a lecture for my spacers but this has been discussed and I've yet to find an alternative that works just as well. Please don't suggest I use margin-left.

http://codepen.io/Compton/pen/zmlAv

```
#content ul.icons {
    width:100%;
    height:130px;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 40px 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
}

#content ul.icons li {
    float:left;
    width:8.03%;
    height:130px;
}

#content ul.icons li a {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    position: relative;
}

#content ul.icons li.option-1 a {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/dfYAoPM.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
}

#content ul.icons li.option-1 a:hover {
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/dfYAoPM.png);
}

#content ul.icon-text {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1% 0 0 0;
    background-color:#f37028;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
}

#content ul.icon-text li {
    float:left;
    width:8.03%;
}

#content ul.icon-text li a {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    margin:11px 0 0 0;
    font-family: 'maven_proregular', Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size:1.2em;
    color:#FFF !important;
}

#content ul.icon-text li a:link, a:active, a:visited {
    color:#FFFFFF !important;
    text-decoration:none !important;
}

#content ul.icon-text li a:hover {
    color:#000000 !important;
    text-decoration:none !important;
}


#content ul li.spacer {
    width:7.29%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
}

<div id="content">

<ul class="icons">
    <li class="option-1"><a href="" title="Option"></a></li>
    <li class="spacer"></li>
    <li class="option-1"><a href="" title="Option"></a></li>
    <li class="spacer"></li>
    <li class="option-1"><a href="" title="Option"></a></li>
    <li class="spacer"></li>
    <li class="option-1"><a href="" title="Option"></a></li>
    <li class="spacer"></li>
    <li class="option-1"><a href="" title="Option"></a></li>
    <li class="spacer"></li>
    <li class="option-1"><a href="" title="Option"></a></li>
    <li class="spacer"></li>
    <li class="option-1"><a href="" title="Option"></a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="icon-text">
    <li><a href="" title="Option">Option</a></li>
    <li class="spacer"></li>
    <li><a href="" title="Option">Option</a></li>
    <li class="spacer"></li>
    <li><a href="" title="Option">Option</a></li>
    <li class="spacer"></li>
    <li><a href="" title="Option">Option</a></li>
    <li class="spacer"></li>
    <li><a href="" title="Option">Option</a></li>
    <li class="spacer"></li>
    <li><a href="" title="Option">Option</a></li>
    <li class="spacer"></li>
    <li><a href="" title="Option">Option</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: if you want it repsonsive use @media only screen and adjust the font-size

Comment: Oh...Lord...it's horrible.

Comment: @Paulie_D - What's that?

Comment: @compton The whole structure. You have two `ul` when one would do. I'm not sure what purpose the `spacers` have (I know you said no lectures) but there are **much** better, simpler and flexible solutions.

Comment: @Paulie_D - Why don't you just say that then instead of being a drama queen about it? We're adults here, aren't we? What's a simpler and more flixible solution instead of the spacers that will do the same job? I've asked this to a few people on here in the past couple weeks. So far nothing. Maybe one of your solutions will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for ?

**[PEN](http://codepen.io/magnus16/pen/tjDrL)**

I used `10vw` as a height for `ul` and `li`. `vw` is viewport width.

Comment: That seems to fix my height problem. Thank you. I'm using vw for my fonts on the page but was guessing they're was a better way so I removed them from this example for less ridicule :) Do you suggest using vw and such going forward and do you see this being adopted more regularly? My only problem with it so far is having to refesh to see the changes when changing screensize manually. Besides that I think it works fantastically. I was looking at it as being too good to be true.

Comment: Honestly, I am also new to vw and vh and didn't really experiment with it. But it looks promising. And you can add a resizing function through jquery if you want

Comment: Thanks boss. I'm starting to agree. Will look into it further.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken before. Your fix solved both my issues.